# Finding_Missing_Dates_between_Dates_From_Data_OracleSQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Need your assistance on finding the missing dates from records, sample below
Currently, i've data for 1, 2, 6 and 10 Jan 2020

```
select p.effective_date,x.xref_security_id,x.xref_type
from securitydbo.price p
inner join securitydbo.xreference x on x.security_alias = p.security_alias
where p.src_intfc_inst = 253
and p.effective_date between ('01-JAN-2020') and ('10-JAN-2020')
and x.xref_security_id = 'ABC999999999'



Expected Results            
    Missing_Date    Xref_Security_ID    Xref_Type   Price
    1/3/2020    ABC99999999             ISIN        0
    1/7/2020    ABC99999999             ISIN        0
    1/8/2020    ABC99999999             ISIN        0
    1/9/2020    ABC99999999             ISIN        0
```

Comment: You may not have those values in your table

Answer (score 1):

I don't have your tables so I created one which looks like result you currently have:

```
SQL> select * From test order by missing_date;

MISSING_DA XREF_S
---------- ------
01/03/2020 ABC999
01/07/2020 ABC999
01/08/2020 ABC999
01/09/2020 ABC999
```

In order to get dates that are missing, create a calendar (see the CTE I used, which is just one of row generator techniques) whose

- starting date is lower date from your period

  - add `level` to it
- `connect by` clause "loops" as many times as there are days in desired period

`XREF_SECURITY_ID` is `NULL` for missing dates as there's no match for them in your tables.

```
SQL> with
  2  -- create a calendar for desired period (see CONNECT BY)
  3  calendar as
  4    (select date '2020-01-01' + level - 1 datum
  5     from dual
  6     connect by level <= date '2020-01-10' - date '2020-01-01' + 1
  7    )
  8  -- outer join calendar with your table(s)
  9  select c.datum, t.xref_security_id
 10  from calendar c left join test t on t.missing_date = c.datum
 11  order by c.datum;

DATUM      XREF_S
---------- ------
01/01/2020
01/02/2020
01/03/2020 ABC999
01/04/2020
01/05/2020
01/06/2020
01/07/2020 ABC999
01/08/2020 ABC999
01/09/2020 ABC999
01/10/2020

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score -1):

I can take a guess that the date_format might be the problem out here. Without actually knowing what is the data in your tables the only way to do is to guess.

```
select p.effective_date,x.xref_security_id,x.xref_type
  from securitydbo.price p
  inner join securitydbo.xreference x on x.security_alias = p.security_alias
 where p.src_intfc_inst = 253
   and p.effective_date between to_date('01-JAN-2020','DD-MON-YYY') 
   and to_date('10-JAN-2020','DD-MON-YYYY')
   and x.xref_security_id = 'ABC999999999'
```

Comment: No its not date fromat issue. Even if the provided date in mm/dd/yyyy format, you don't have consecutive date values.

Comment: @JimMacaulay -ve vote?. The OP says, i've data for 1, 2, 6 and 10 Jan 2020. Yet in the expected results he says 3,7,8,9 (4 and 5 goes missing). I have explained it could be possible that you possibly got a date format issue that might have caused the missing ones. And also i mention that without knowing the only way is to guess.